# Background thread in WCF services

Tags: c#, wcf

I have developed a WCF service for serving our customers and hosted it on IIS. We have a requirement to log all the requests received and responses sent from WCF in to a database.

But, because of this logging, we don't want to interrupt main flow of requests and responses. So, we are using threads (`Threading.Thread` and `Thread.IsBackground = true`) to call procedures to insert/log the requests and responses to database.

I just want to know if there will be problems in implementing/invoking threads on a WCF service. If so, what will be a good solution for this?

Comment: There's no problem running tasks or threads from inside a WCF request, but each WCF request is processed on it's own thread, if that's any help.

Comment: Are you sure your are not optimizing this prematurely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there can be a problem. The application pool in IIS can get recycled which means that the background thread will be killed, even if it's in the middle of some processing.

In reality that will only be a problem when you update your application (as the logger should be done when the app pool is stopped due to the idle timeout).

So if you can live with lost log entries during updates you do not have a problem.

Comment: IIS creates a new instance of the pool and routes new requests there whilst it waits for the old one to finish. Thread.IsBackground = false will keep it open I suspect in the same way GUI apps continue to run even after closing the main window.

Comment: @MickyDuncan there is a timeout variable set in iis (I can't remember its exact name) but it is the maximum amount of time the app pool will have from the last request to do any processing, even if it is a forgound thread. If it is still processing when the timeout happens IIS issues a `Thread.Abort()` on the thread.

Comment: @MickyDuncan found it, it is the [Shutdown Time Limit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2634635/en-us)

Comment: @jgauffin Yes, it seems IIS will nuke the app pool even if **IsBackground = false**.  This is different behaviour under WinForms where the process continues to run after the window was closed